# Out of Memory Exception while working with Images in .NET(VB.Net 2008)

Tags: vb.net, image, memory-leaks, bitmap

I am facing a strange issue while dealing with big images ( size approx 48 mb, a Tiff file having 175 pages.). Now when I am trying to convert the Imagefile into the bitmap and doing some operation, randomly system will throw "Out of memory exception"

Below is my code snippet. I am getting error (randomly) on line " pages = New Bitmap(lorigionalFile) " where LoriginalFile is of ImageType and Page is of Bitmap.

So Please guide me what to do to remove this type of error or stoping the memory leakage.

---

```
        Dim lorigionalFile As System.Drawing.Image
        Dim SaveEncodeParam As EncoderParameter 'Encoder parameter to create multi page image
        Dim EncoderParams As EncoderParameters = New EncoderParameters(1) 'Encoder parameter Array
        Dim pages As Bitmap 'Used to save image page
        Dim NextPage As Bitmap 'Used to save next image page
        Dim PageNumber As Integer
        Lfr = File.Open(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)

        lorigionalFile = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Lfr)

        ''Get number of page count in image
        PageNumber = getPageNumber(lorigionalFile)

        'set first page as active frame
        cintPagenumber = PageNumber

        'loop to every page of attached document
        For i As Integer = 0 To PageNumber - 1
            'set active from as per loop variable
            lorigionalFile.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i)

            'Will get errow in below line(randomly), when there are other programs running in background
            pages = New Bitmap(lorigionalFile)

               'image store in Image
                CalImageContainer.Add(pages)
                'make a copy on image container
                CalImageContainerCopy.Add(pages)

        Next
        Lfr.Close()

    End Try
```

Thanks

Pratik vohera

Answer (score 0):

I don't know VB, but it looks like you create a new bitmap memory in your for-loop above without freeing the memory in between.

Use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) instead to extract images from tif and then operate on each of those instead.

Just a thought.